# Syncing contacts between devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization, contacts, accounts

How people sync contacts between devices on PC, Tablet, Phone?

When i use same apple account on my ipad and iphone it is ok but it is not possible to sync with my Android Tablet (google account) and my PC (Microsoft Account)

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an Apple account. You can sync contacts from Google or Microsoft accounts with iOS devices, so use one of those accounts to store your contacts.